# android buttons to switch between two screens

Tags: button, layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am a beginner of android application. I am using Android Studio to make an application for a shopping cart list. For the start, right now, I am working on the creating two buttons on each screens that called, "edit" and "save." So if I click the edit button, it will go to screen2, and if I click the save, it will go to screen1. However, Whenever I tried to lunch it, it's getting an error like this:

```
02-14 15:14:57.830 AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jieun.hw1, PID: 1782
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jieun.hw1/com.example.jieun.hw1.MainActivityOne}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My codes for two screens and the layouts are something like this:

Screen1:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

Button editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.e_button);

editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Starting a new Intent
        Intent editScreen = new Intent(..MainActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(editScreen);
    }
});
```

}

Screen2:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s_button);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Starting a new Intent
                Intent saveScreen;
                saveScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivityOne.class);
                startActivity(saveScreen);
            }
        });

   }
```

Layout1:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityOne">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Edit"
    android:id="@+id/e_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Layout2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityOne">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/s_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking through your code for screen 1?

Here:

```
  //Starting a new Intent 
        Intent editScreen = new Intent(..MainActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(editScreen);
    }
```

There are two periods before MainActivityTwo.class

Comment: ya it is not actually period, but Intent editScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivityTwo.class);

Comment: @JieunChon Well that is what the code you posted says, and in "Layout1" you are missing a closing tag for `RelativeLayout`. Also, in your `setContentView` you are referencing `R.id.activity_list`, for both activities. Shouldn't they be two different layouts that are being referenced?